# Storing page views from Google Analytics 4 on Backend

Tags: google-analytics, nestjs, google-analytics-4

On the backend, I have Nest.js + PostgreSQL, and the only problem that needs to be solved is views for posts. I've been trying to find some information on Google and YouTube for a few days, but I haven't found anything useful, and I couldn't find any implementation examples either.

On the frontend, we send a request to api/posts/:id. Maybe we need to send a request to the Google API: ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/ and save the views, but when and what will trigger this "saving"?

Sending a request to the Google API every time is bad idea I think; it will likely interfere with caching in Nest.js (@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't send a request on every hit. You don't even connect storing pageviews to active sessions, unless you wanna have an independed parallel tracking, which your web server kinda already does for you in the access logs.

Otherwise, generally 2 options.

1. You store them with about 2-day delay, having a batch daily download script downloading all the hits from 2 days before, then you should have an ETL process in place where you stitch the limited API data responses into a fuller picture in your DB.
2. You do all that but with Google's internal tools and exporting all that raw data directly to BQ. No coding required. Now, getting that data from BQ to anywhere you want is a lot easier.

The second option requires so mmuch less dev time, that it's now become a default for exporting data from GA4. Only GA4 though.

Comment: Thank you very much! It set me on the right way. But what about the views in almost real time, ie as soon as the user has viewed the page we update the views in our database, or maybe i not understanding correctly?

Comment: If you need it in real time, Google Analytics is not your tool. Either use your access logs, or use a different analytics solution. Maybe a custom one. I think Matomo offers real-time data access.

Comment: I've seen several sites running on Universal Analytics and their views on backend are updated as soon as a user clicks on a post. Was it possible in UA? Also thanks for the info about Matomo, I'll try

Comment: No, UA has had similar delay of up to four hours for paid UA (called UA 360), and up to two days for the free version. You might have been looking at the backend using its own analytics, unaffiliated with UA. Some CMSes have their own small local analytics, storing the data locally and requiring no time-consuming processing to display the data.

Comment: It seems so, but I found a solution, the idea of Matomo with the storage of analytics on its own server seemed very convenient to me. umami.is lightweight and useful

Comment: Oh yes, umami looks very convenient. I should try it out when I have time. See if maybe it's good enough to replace GA4. Cuz the market needs a replacement for it. GA4 adds way too many limitations, even the paid version of it.

Comment: oh,smth i didnt take into. There one problem, views calculated based on number of events. Backend returns post from db, it should also include views, e.g: {id:1, title:"amazing post", views:32}, but even if take response from db (id + title) and combine it with views into one object, will be issue with pagination. and idk what do. if get views with api, we will also have pagination issues and additional latency. I thought about getting views per request, but thats bad idea, even with caching. I tried to find alternative but others were bit confusing, umami looks best and comfortable on Next.js